# Error calling a TypeScript function in firebase cloud function

Tags: node.js, typescript, google-cloud-functions, typescript-generics

I have some issue writing typescripe code for a firebase cloud function.
I assume it is mainly a syntax problem.

The code is below, but the relevant part is the what concerns the call of the myLocalFunc function. The rest is only here to provide some context. The part reading:

```
response:Response<any>
```

in:

```
const myLocalFunc = (mail:string, flag:boolean, response:Response<any>) => {...}
```

is wrong. Because I get this error message:

```
error TS2315: Type 'Response' is not generic.
```

**What is the proper syntax?**

```
const myLocalFunc = (mail:string, flag:boolean, response:Response<any>) => {
    admin.auth().getUserByEmail(mail)
        .then(function(userRecord) {
          // Do some useful work.
          const data = {
            boolField: flag,
          };
          const refStr = "/Users/"+userRecord.uid;
          admin.database().ref(refStr).set(data);
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
          console.log("Error fetching user data:", error);
          let rspMsg = "This user (";
          rspMsg += mail;
          rspMsg += ") does not exists.";
          response.send(rspMsg);
        });
  };
  
  
  exports.myFunc = functions.https.onRequest(function(req, resp) {
  resp.set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  resp.set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST");

  corsHandler(req, resp, async () => {
    const from = String(req.body.from);
    const idToken = String(req.body.token);

    admin.auth().verifyIdToken(idToken)
        .then(function(decodedToken) {
          const uid = decodedToken.uid;
          const refStr = "/Users/"+uid;
          const ref = admin.database().ref(refStr);

          ref.on("value", function(snapshot) {
            console.log("snapshot.val():", snapshot.val());
            if (snapshot.val() !== undefined) {
              const snv = snapshot.val();
              if (snv.adminRights !== undefined) {
                if (snv.adminRights) {
                  // Only if we reach this point,
                  // can we perform the operation next line.
                  myLocalFunc(from, true, resp);
                }
              }
            }
          }, function(errorObject) {
            console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject);
          });
        }).catch(function(error) {
          // Handle error
          functions.logger.log("(FL)error:", error);
          console.log("(CL)error:", error);
        });
  }); // End corsHandler.
});
```

Note:

I got the idea of trying Response<any> for the type (without much conviction) after reading some some documentation for *functions.https.onRequest*.

If I change the code to:

```
const myLocalFunc = (mail:string, flag:boolean, response) => {...}
```

which is in fact what I started with.

I get this error:

```
error TS7006: Parameter 'response' implicitly has an 'any' type.
```

If I try to change the code to this:

```
const myLocalFunc = (mail:string, flag:boolean, response:Response) => {...}
```

I get these two errors:

```
37:18 - error TS2339: Property 'send' does not exist on type 'Response'.
37         response.send(rspMsg); // This works.
                ~~~~

79:46 - error TS2345: Argument of type 'Response<any>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Response'.
Type 'Response<any>' is missing the following properties from type 'Response': headers, ok, redirected, statusText, and 9 more.

79                   myLocalFunc(from, true, resp);
```

Comment: Try `response:Response` without `<any>` or can you show where is Response imported from?

Comment: I suggest editing the question to show the *complete, minimal* example that reproduces this problem.  Show the entire file, and strip out everything that's not directly part of the problem. You should also show your package.json so we can see the versions of libraries you're using. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: The last parameter of myLocalFunc is coming from the last parameter of functions.https.onRequest(function(req, resp), which is resp. I guess I only need to write its type in the myLocalFunc prototype (or signature). I also added a note at the end of the post, please take a look.

Comment: I do not import Response from anywhere. I just needed to put a type for the last parameter and did quite know what to put.

Comment: Try `import { Response } from "express"` and then using `Response` as type there.

Comment: Response without <any> did not work, see my updated post.

Comment: @Dharmaraj. Yes you are right, using Response and importing doing import {Response} from "express"; (with no space between the braces, or Typescript complains) works. If you want to put this as an answer I can only accept it.

Comment: Posted one. You can also check what interface you are importing by hovering on it and IDE should show the definition of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `req` and `res` parameters in `onRequest()` are [Request](https://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html#req) and [Response](https://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html#res) objects from Express. When not importing Response from Express, it's another interface which also is not generic.

```
import {Response} from "express";

const myLocalFunc = (mail: string, flag: boolean, response: Response) => {...}
```

Comment: I removed the spaces on both sides of "Response" in the first line otherwise it does not work.

Comment: That might be your code formatter with some warnings.